# I tried to delete data using ajax but not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

When I tried to delete id by using ajax, it is not working.
I have tried many ways using the route name and also using route.
But it cannot work.

My view page code is :

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="delete-product" data-id="{{ $product->id }}" class="btn btn-danger delete-product">Delete</a>
```

My controller code is :

```
function removedata(Request $request)
{
    $product= Product::find($request->input('id'));
    if($product->delete())
    {
        echo 'Data Deleted';
    }
}
```

My route is :

```
Route::get('/product/remove', 'Product\ProductController@removedata')->name('product.remove');
```

My script is :

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
    $('body').on('click', '.delete-product', function () {
        var user_id = $(this).data("id");   

        if(confirm("Are you sure you want to Delete this data?"))
        {
            $.ajax({
                url:"{{route('product.remove')}}",
                mehtod:"get",
                data:user_id,
                success:function(data)
                {
                    alert("sucess");
                }
            })
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$product= Product::find($request->input('id'));
dd($product);--------------------------->(What is the output here)
if($product->delete())
{
    echo 'Data Deleted';
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Check this and update your code:

```
$product= Product::where('id',$request->input('id'))->delete();
    if($product)
    {
        echo 'Data Deleted';
    }
```